# Pygame cannot load image from same directory as script

Tags: image, python-2.7, directory, load, pygame

So I installed python 2.7.8 and the latest pygame, but I can't seem to get image.load () to find my image file, despite several attempts to rename and recheck the spelling. The image and script that use it are in the same directory. Has anyone run into similar issues?

```
self.src_image = pygame.image.load
```

Is the line in question. `image` is used as a parameter that is filled later with a specific file name.

Here is some context:

```
import pygame, math, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 786))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class WitchSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     speed = 10
     acceleration = .4

     def __init__(self, image, position):
         pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
         self.src_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image))
         self.postion = position
         self.speed = self.direction = 0
         self.k_left = self.k_right = self.k_down = self.k_up = 0
```

Comment: It always helps to post the relevant code; it'll be harder to troubleshoot your problem just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Show more code - How do you use that `self.src_image` and **WHY** do you assign function name `pygame.image.load` to `self.src_image` ?

Comment: Where is the code that you're using to load your actual `.png` file?

Answer (score 0):

First, check that your image can even be loaded. Use `pygame.image.get_extended()` to check if  it will load image formats. It should return `True`.

The pygame docs say that you should "use os.path.join() for compatibility." Try to load your image using `os` and see if that takes care of your problem.

ex: "`asurf = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data', 'bla.png'))`"

Comment: Get extended returned true, and now there seems to be an error on the line below the image line, so hopefully after I fix that, it will work. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Turns out I missed a close parentheses, the issue is exactly the same as before. I'm fearful that I somehow messed up my install or something of the sort. Because this issue has been here the entire time that I have had pygame and it doesn't seem to be an issue for many people.

Comment: Consistently, it gives me: 
'File"C:\Users...\game\movingthing.py", line 13, in __init__
   self.src_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image))
pygame.error: Couldn't open w.png'